# How to use Test Setup (ROBOTFRAMEWORK) in another tests cases?

Tags: robotframework

I need to select a database information to fill some input text in my test case.

I got error  Setting 'Test Setup' is not allowed in suite initialization file.

```
*** Settings ***

Resource  ${ROOT}/path/main.resource

Test Setup          Test setup from __init__.robot
#
*** Keywords ***

access some menu
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `__init__.robot` you should change to:

```
Suite Setup
```

Then you don't call it in each Test.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an exemple of a `__init__.robot` that you could use

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Screenshot

Suite Setup         TAKE SCREENSHOT
```

This will be automatically executed for every test inside your Test Suite